# flask-sqlalchemy max value of column

Tags: python, sqlalchemy, flask, flask-sqlalchemy

Lets say I have a user model as such

```
from flask import Flask
from flask.ext.sqlalchemy import SQLAlchemy

app = Flask(__name__)
app.config['SQLALCHEMY_DATABASE_URI'] = 'sqlite:////tmp/test.db'
db = SQLAlchemy(app)


class User(db.Model):
    id = db.Column(db.Integer, primary_key=True)
    username = db.Column(db.String(80), unique=True)
    email = db.Column(db.String(120), unique=True)
    numLogins = db.Column(db.Integer)

    def __init__(self, username, email):
        self.username = username
        self.email = email

    def __repr__(self):
        return '<User %r>' % self.username
```

How do I query the records for user with maximum logins?

Answer (score 21, accepted):

You could order by `numLogins` and take the first result, but that won't work if multiple people have the same number. Instead, find the max number, then find all users with that number.

```
from sqlalchemy import func

max_logins = db.session.query(func.max(User.numLogins)).scalar()
users = db.session.query(User).filter(User.numLogins == max_logins).all()
```

You could reduce this to one query.

```
sub = db.session.query(func.max(User.numLogins).label('ml')).subquery()
users = db.session.query(User).join(sub, sub.c.ml == User.numLogins).all()
```

Answer (score 2):

Problem:

max num items from a buy with  id == params

```
from sqlalchemy import func
```

--

```
max_numite = db.session.query(func.max(DetCompra.numite)).filter(
DetCompra.numcom == id_compra).scalar()
```

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).